# How do I get the list of user emails shared by gspread google API?

Tags: python, gspread

I've created some google spreadsheets using the gspread and shared with some lists of emails with different permissions. Is there a way to somehow get the list or dict of these emails and permissions?

This is more or less my code:

```
import gspread as gs

gc = gs.service_account_from_dict(JSON_KEY)

gs = gc.create('new_spreadsheet')
ws = gs.add_worksheet(title='new_worksheet', rows='100', cols='12')
gs.del_worksheet(gs.worksheet('Sheet1'))

std_writers = ['email_1@email.com', 'email_2@email.com', 'email_3@email.com', 'email_4@email.com']
std_viewers = ['email_5@email.com', 'email_6@email.com', 'email_7@email.com', 'email_8@email.com']

for writer in std_writers:
    gs.share(email_address=writer, perm_type='user', role='writer')
        
for viewer in std_viewers:
    gs.share(email_address=viewer, perm_type='user', role='reader')
```

I was expecting to use the gspread to return these emails to double check and also to get the updated list o users in case someone with the writer's permission had shared with someone.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is.

See below link, you can list all email that share that spreadsheet using: `gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.list_permission()` method.

In your case it should be something like:

```py
gs.list_permissions()
```

https://docs.gspread.org/en/master/api/models/spreadsheet.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.list_permissions